# How to secure access to HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext

Tags: security, authentication, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, thrift

I want to read data from Hadoop and make it available in memory through SparkSQL so I can use a NodeJS application to access it with low latency.

Since the data is sensitive I need to ensure whoever is accessing this thrift server instance has the required access.

I don't know too much about thrift server with Spark but I understand that I should provide a username and password in my application to authenticate against the server.

How can I do that? Define a username and password in my Thrift or Spark code/environment and use that in my JDBC / ODBC calls?

Thanks!